# isLiked() equivalent code when using LikeView (com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView)?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have successfully implemented LikeView in my android app.Everything is working fine.

I am interested to reward User who liked my app. Is there any event by which i can Implement reward code.

Thanks in Advance :)

Here is my code of LikeView

```
likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.LikeView);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType("https://www.facebook.com/BrightnessDimmer",LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
likeView.setHorizontalAlignment(LikeView.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their doc, it's not possible.
Maybe, if your rewards are not "sensitive rewards", you could save user action click in SharedPreferences...

Answer (score 0):

The result of pressing like button can be obtained from `onActivityResult()`.

First, u need to create a Facebook `CallbackManager` in the Activity where LikeView is handled:

```
private CallbackManager mFacebookCallbackManager;
//... in the onCreate() or other methods
// For Facebook SDK v4
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
        mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}
```

Then in the `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (null != data) {
        if ("com.facebook.platform.action.request.LIKE_DIALOG".equals(data.getStringExtra("com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_ACTION"))) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras().getBundle("com.facebook.platform.protocol.RESULT_ARGS");
            if (bundle != null) {
                // Here your get the like result
                System.out.printf("Facebook like result:%b\n", bundle.getBoolean("object_is_liked"));
                mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.